# Original url when using nginx container as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, docker, single-sign-on

I have a web application deployed as a *docker container*. I also have an **nginx** container (using *dnsmasq* resolver) set up to act as a reverse proxy in front of the web application, it's 80 port mapped to the host. My application uses SSO authentication.

When I log in using my identity provider, the callback url seems to be my web application's internal domain name, not the proper url on the host machine.

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
    resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=1s ipv6=off;
    set $upstream_endpoint http://myapp:5000;
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;
    }
}
```

The callback url to which the sso tries to redirect is http://myapp:5000 not http://myhost.com:80, which is obviously fails since it is internal.

Could somebody please help me find how to set nginx up properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this directive into location:

`proxy_set_header Host myhost.com;`