# How do I change the server name in the links in a Spring RepositoryRestResource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I've got a simple RepositoryRestResource based off of the guides on spring.io

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long>{

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name")  String lastName);

}
```

This does indeed work, as my REST client returns

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "people" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/people{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

But my question is, where does the `http://127.0.0.1:8080` part of the `_links` come from and how can I change it? When my application goes to production (or any of my environments, like local or dev), I'd rather be able to see something like `http://api.mydomain.com`.

If it matters, I'm compiling my program with `mvn package` and running it as a standalone jar on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host and port of your URL are figured out by using [HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) (or `getRequestURI`). So it will always reflect the host and port used by the client when performing the request.

Once you deploy that as `api.yourdomain.com`, this is what you'll get in the link URLs.

Comment: That certainly is the case! I was getting thrown off because when we deploy, we're actually deploying in Docker containers with an nginx reverse proxy server in front so it always looked like localhost:8080 to Spring.

I changed the nginx config as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791634/original-url-when-using-nginx-container-as-reverse-proxy and it works as expected.